# How do I get what the Friday (day name ) 2 weeks from the present date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I really need your help with this,

What I would like to accomplish is being able to return the date value ( the day name ) after two weeks starting from today, in this example it's gonna be Friday.

```
var present_date = Thursday, November 23, 2017

var result_date =  Friday, December 8, 2017 // after two weeks

function present_date_plus_2weeks() {

    var now = new Date()

    now.setDate(now.getDate()+14)

    alert(now)

}
```

It gets the date 2 weeks from the present date, but I need the code to get the Friday (the day name)

Impossible to do?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Define 2 weeks. Last Friday within next 14 days or ??

Comment: Within next 14 days, the next Friday date is Dec. 8, 2017

Comment: If the date isn't Friday, which one do you want, the previous or next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code and what i understand from it:

```
var present_date = new Date();

var days = ['Monday', 'tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

function present_date_plus_2weeks() {

    var now = new Date()

    now.setDate(now.getDate()+14)

    var numDay = now.getDay(); 
    alert(days[numDay]);

}

present_date_plus_2weeks();
```

However, i would recommend using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

with that you can simply do :

```
var afterTwoWeeks = new moment().add(14, 'days').format('dddd');
```

Comment: I will gladly accept your answer and would like to thank you. I have the momentjs library, what would be format for this if this is the easier route?

Comment: thank you , glad i could help :) , i edited my answer to provide an example using `Moment.js`

Comment: Where does this get the Friday?

Comment: @RobG, if it's about MomentJs, it's built in, english by default, if you want other languages you have to import the `locale` for it, check theire website for more details, if it's about my answer, it's in the array :P , it doesn't matter if it's Friday or another day, the guy wants to display the day name after 14 days from today :)

Comment: Ok, so the OP was actually asking "how do I get the day name 2 weeks from today", but that will just be the same day name as today.

Answer (score 1):

The day name in 14 days will be the same as today's day name, but in case you want to use some other increment, you can adjust the date as in other questions, then use *toLocaleString* with options:

```js
// Current date
var d = new Date();

// Two weeks hence
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 14);

// Get day name in host language
var dayName = d.toLocaleString(undefined,{weekday:'long'})

console.log(dayName);
```